# SpringBootAdmin Server fails to run - Error processing condition on org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.audit.AuditAutoConfiguration

Tags: spring-boot, maven, spring-boot-admin

I am trying to set up a Spring Boot Admin Server in VS Code with Maven. I've created a new project and added the SpringBoot Admin Server dependency,

I added the @EnableAdminServer annotation to my main class and ran the server application, but I am getting an error:

```
2022-03-16 15:34:46.579 ERROR 4444 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error processing condition on org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.audit.AuditAutoConfiguration
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:60) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.0.0-M1.jar:3.0.0-M1] 
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConditionEvaluator.java:108) ~[spring-context-6.0.0-M2.jar:6.0.0-M2]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader$TrackedConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:477) ~[spring-context-6.0.0-M2.jar:6.0.0-M2]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:139) ~[spring-context-6.0.0-M2.jar:6.0.0-M2]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:128) ~[spring-context-6.0.0-M2.jar:6.0.0-M2]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:343) ~[spring-context-6.0.0-M2.jar:6.0.0-M2]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:247) ~[spring-context-6.0.0-M2.jar:6.0.0-M2]
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:307) 
~[spring-context-6.0.0-M2.jar:6.0.0-M2]
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:108) ~[spring-context-6.0.0-M2.jar:6.0.0-M2]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:746) ~[spring-context-6.0.0-M2.jar:6.0.0-M2]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:564) ~[spring-context-6.0.0-M2.jar:6.0.0-M2]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.reactive.context.ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.java:64) ~[spring-boot-3.0.0-M1.jar:3.0.0-M1]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:719) ~[spring-boot-3.0.0-M1.jar:3.0.0-M1]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:401) ~[spring-boot-3.0.0-M1.jar:3.0.0-M1]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:302) ~[spring-boot-3.0.0-M1.jar:3.0.0-M1]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1290) ~[spring-boot-3.0.0-M1.jar:3.0.0-M1]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1279) ~[spring-boot-3.0.0-M1.jar:3.0.0-M1]
        at com.aaman.springbootadmin.SpringbootadminApplication.main(SpringbootadminApplication.java:13) ~[classes/:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-3.0.0-M1.jar:3.0.0-M1]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [de.codecentric.boot.admin.server.ui.config.AdminServerUiAutoConfiguration] from ClassLoader [jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@6d5380c2]
        at             ... 38 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.thymeleaf.spring5.templateresolver.SpringResourceTemplateResolver
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        42 common frames omitted
    2022-03-16 15:34:46.597  WARN 4444 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Unable to close ApplicationContext
    
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [de.codecentric.boot.admin.server.ui.config.AdminServerUiAutoConfiguration] from ClassLoader [jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@6d5380c2]
            at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:479) ~[spring-core-6.0.0-M2.jar:6.0.0-M2]
...            at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
            at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-3.0.0-M1.jar:3.0.0-M1]
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/thymeleaf/spring5/templateresolver/SpringResourceTemplateResolver
            at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
            at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
            at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
            at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:461) ~[spring-core-6.0.0-M2.jar:6.0.0-M2]
            ... 26 common frames omitted
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.thymeleaf.spring5.templateresolver.SpringResourceTemplateResolver
            at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
            at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
            at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
            ... 30 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the resolution:

Apparently Spring Boot Admin incompatible with released Spring Boot 3.0.0-M1 - I changed my Spring Boot version to 2.6.4 and it is running successfully.